# pyModbusTCP timeout inside Docker container

Tags: python, docker, modbus, pymodbustcp, wago

I have a similar issue like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72959652/unkown-cause-of-pymodbustcp-timeout). But effect the effect is limited to pyModbusTCP inside a Docker container and a WAGO 750-8000.

I initialize the Modbus client by inside a Docker container:

```
mc = ModbusClient(host="192.168.100.1", port=502, debug=True, timeout=0.1)
```

When I'm trying to read the registers with:

```
mc.read_holding_registers(256, 50)
```

I'm getting a timeout error:

```
Tx
[B9 AE 00 00 00 06 01] 03 01 00 00 32
timeout error
```

If i increase the timout (to 0.7 or higher) it works. At least sometimes.

The interesting thing is, if I do the same Python Code on the host machine (Windows 10), then it works, even with a very short timeout of 0.01s.

Also:
With a different Modbus device (an older WAGO 750-832) it works (out of docker container).

Any ideas, which component may be configured wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So things had nothing to do with the mentioned libs and software.
Problem was a bug in WAGO 750-8000 Modbus implementation. Fix comes with a firmware update.